# Why it is not allowed to put a filter in a projection

Tags: projection, vertica

I have a conceptual question on Vertica Projection. Why it is not allowed to put a filter in a projection ? My intention of asking this question is - I have a requirement where I need to dynamically access data from either full table or from a partial last 3 days data based on a UI filter criteria.If filter was allowed, I would have created 2 different projection ,one with last 3 days data filter condition and then other with full data.

Answer (score 0):

Use views for this purpose that are hitting the same projection but have their own predicates.